# Comando SQL dentro de uma variavel varchar - sql server

Tags: sql-server

Boa Tarde
Preciso escrever um comando dentro de uma variável do formato varchar

```
Set @STRING_SQL = 'update BCS_RESOURCE set DS_DESCRICAO = ''Gestão de Contratos - ''+ @DS_PERFIL + '' ,  [DS_pt-BR] = ''Gestão de Contratos - '+ @DS_PERFIL + ', DS_en-EN = ''Gestão de Contratos - '''+ @DS_PERFIL + ''', DS_es-ES = ''Gestão de Contratos -  '''+ @DS_PERFIL + '''  where ID_RESOURCE = '--+ CAST(@id_Resource as VARCHAR(100))
```

mas ainda não estou conseguindo fazer o exec esta dando erro de concatenação de string

Comment: Você pode se explicar melhor? Não entendi o seu problema. Você não sabe como atualizar as 3 colunas novas dentro do mesmo update, ou você está recebendo uma mensagem de erro (nesse caso, qual)?

Comment: Não. eu não estou conseguindo colocar o comando de update dentro de um varchar.
 exemplo:   set @Variavel_Varchar = 'Comando update '

Comment: ainda esta dando erro

Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Gestão de Contratos -  Solicitante  where ID_RESOURCE = 2003'.

Comment: Pode atualizar sua pergunta com o código completo?

Comment: agora atualizado

Comment: alterei a resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça.

```
declare @DS_PERFIL varchar(100) = 'teste', @id_Resource int = 1, @SeuValor varchar(100) =' Seu Valor', @STRING_SQL varchar(max)

Set @STRING_SQL = 'update BCS_RESOURCE set DS_DESCRICAO = ''Gestão de Contratos - '+ @DS_PERFIL + ''' ,  [DS_pt-BR] = ''Gestão de Contratos - '+ @DS_PERFIL + ''', DS_en-EN = ''Gestão de Contratos - '+ @DS_PERFIL + ''', DS_es-ES = ''Gestão de Contratos -  '+ @DS_PERFIL + '''  where ID_RESOURCE =  '+ @DS_PERFIL + ''
print @STRING_SQL



update BCS_RESOURCE 
set DS_DESCRICAO = 'Gestão de Contratos - teste' ,  
[DS_pt-BR] = 'Gestão de Contratos - teste',
 DS_en-EN = 'Gestão de Contratos - teste', 
 DS_es-ES = 'Gestão de Contratos -  teste' 
  where ID_RESOURCE =  teste
```

> Não esqueça de acrescentar um as aspas caso seu campo seja do tipo
>   `varchar`. Tipo  DS_pt-BR = '''+ @SeuValor + '''

Comment: Obrigado. o seu código estava certo, o problema era o tamanho da minha variável varchar(250)

Answer (score 1):

Veja se agora vai

```
Set @STRING_SQL = 'update BCS_RESOURCE set DS_DESCRICAO = ''Gestão de Contratos - ''+ @DS_PERFIL ,  [DS_pt-BR] = ''Gestão de Contratos - ''+ @DS_PERFIL + , DS_en-EN = ''Gestão de Contratos - ''+ @DS_PERFIL +, DS_es-ES = ''Gestão de Contratos -  ''+ @DS_PERFIL + where ID_RESOURCE = '--+ CAST(@id_Resource as VARCHAR(100))
```

Comment: A variavel @DS_PERFIL esta sendo lida como um varchar. o conteudo dela não foi reconhecido

Answer (score 1):

Você está fechando a string com duas aspas simples quando vai fazer a concatenação.

As **duas** aspas simples são o escape para incluir **uma** aspas na string, então para fechar a string basta uma aspas e para reabrir e inserir uma aspas **dentro** da string você usa **três**.

Confuso, mas acho que o código abaixo esclarece e corrige o erro.

```
Set @STRING_SQL = 
    'update BCS_RESOURCE ' +
    'set ' +
        'DS_DESCRICAO = ''Gestão de Contratos - ' + @DS_PERFIL + ''', ' +
        'DS_pt-BR     = ''Gestão de Contratos - ' + @DS_PERFIL + ''', ' +
        'DS_en-EN     = ''Gestão de Contratos - ' + @DS_PERFIL + ''', ' +
        'DS_es-ES     = ''Gestão de Contratos - ' + @DS_PERFIL + ''' ' +
    'where ' +
        'ID_RESOURCE = ' + CAST(@id_Resource as VARCHAR(100))
```

Comment: esta dando o erro:
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Gestão de Contratos - Gerente Fin'.

Comment: E "Gerente Fin" é o valor de DS_PERFIL, certo?
Eu não consegui encontrar nenhuma plica faltando...

Comment: Já verdade seria "Gerente Financeiro" este esta cortando a string

Comment: Você pode imprimir STRING_SQL pelo código e postar aqui?